# XPS to Doc(x) Conversion via .Net?

Tags: .net, ms-office, docx, doc, wordml

Does anyone know of a (native) .net way to convert xps documents to docx or finally to a normal (non wordml) .doc? As in not using office automation and rather some native (3rd party) .net library that might help me there?

Basically the xps > doc transformation will take place on a server with multiple concurrently running 'jobs' & automating office has proven to be somehwat.. flakey...

Does anyone know of such a lib?

Answer (score 1):

.Net framework 3.0 has an inteface for reading (and writing) XPS. The XPS classes is a part of the Windows Presentation Foundation, WPF, and is found under the System.Windows.Xps namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This type of task is what Word Automation Services is for (in Sharepoint 2010). There's a code sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff181518.aspx for batch-converting DOCX files into PDF.

However... I can't quite work out whether XPS is actually supported as a format to open files in. You might want to double-check that before buying Sharepoint.

Chris

Comment: Just noticed the date on this - it's possible you've found some way around it in the last couple of years...